# "Tensorflow + NNAPI" runs very slow on Samsung Galaxy S21

Tags: tensorflow-lite, nnapi

`Samsung Galaxy S21` is the only device runs slow when using `tensor-flow lite` and `NNAPI` together. Did anyone encounter this issue before?

**Background**

I used `tensor-flow lite` and `NNAPI` and built my app on different Android devices. `Samsung Galaxy S21` is VERY slow (0.5 fps); All other devices (including `Samsung Galaxy S20`) is fast (12-20 fps).

Without using `NNAPI`, using GPU/CPU delegates, `Samsung Galaxy S21` can run at (9-10 fps).

**Implementation:**

I set interpreter to use NNAPI:

```
TfLiteInterpreterOptionsSetUseNNAPI(m_options, true);
```

and then invoke interpreter using:

```
TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(m_interpreter);
```

**Result:**

I time stamped `TfLiteInterpreterInvoke()` method on different Android devices. Here are the results:

- Samsung Galaxy S21: **860** ms;
- Samsung Galaxy S20: 10 ms;
- Any other android devices: 10-30 ms;

**Profiled Trace**

Then I used Android Profiler to trace the CPU usage in `Samsung Galaxy S21`:

```
ANeuralNetworksExecution_compute()                    --- 851 ms
    compute()                                         --- 851 ms
       ...
          [kernel.kallsysms]+ 0xffffffc---------().   --- 851 ms 
          [kernel.kallsysms]+ 0xffffffc---------().   --- 851 ms 
          [kernel.kallsysms]+ 0xffffffc---------().   --- 851 ms
          .....
```

It looks like the majority of the time is spent on the GPU kernels. Does this mean `S21` GPU is not compatible with NNAPI and tensorflow?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `adb shell setprop debug.nn.vlog 1`, rerun the test and share the logcat?